# Query to update a field in appengine datastore entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a `ndb.Model` called `Article`. It has a number of entities, say 1000. The model has `title`, `author`, `date`, `content`. Say all my titles contain the phrase `by Kasav Bere` somewhere in the title string.

Is there a way to run a query on the datastore that would remove all occurences of `by Kasav Bere`. I keep searching, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such query.

You can either 1) fetch all entities, remove all "by Kasav Bere", and put them back.
Or 2) use mapreduce 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview

For 1000 entities, I would recommend just fetch all entities and put them back.

You can easily do this kind of task with remote shell 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api

Comment: I don't fully understand the google quota system, so I try to be very thrifty. I ended up doing it by hands. Thanks for your reply, anyway.